# Passing filename to variable in Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell

I have hundreds of file in working directory that needs to be processed. It looks similar to this

```
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
d.txt
```

All of these file can be processed manually like this

```
$lines = Get-Content "a.txt"
foreach ($line in $lines){
  Out-File -FilePath "a-done.txt" -Encoding UTF8 -Append -InputObject ($line.Split(","))[0]
}
```

How to automate this process using loop by passing all filename to variable above.

I have tried foreach loop but it's not working

```
$lines = Get-Content "path/*.txt"
foreach ($line in $lines){
  Out-File -FilePath "$lines-processed.txt" -Encoding UTF8 -Append -InputObject ($line.Split(","))[0]
}
```

What do I miss here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To discover the files themselves, you'll want to use `Get-ChildItem` instead of `Get-Content`! To reference the file name *without* the extension (ie. `a` from `a.txt`), reference the `BaseName` property:

```bsh
foreach($file in Get-ChildItem .\path\ -Filter *.txt){
  foreach ($line in $file |Get-Content){
    Out-File -FilePath "$($file.BaseName)-done.txt" -Encoding UTF8 -Append -InputObject ($line.Split(","))[0]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Youre looping through the lines of get-content, not where the filenames are saved. You need probably an extra step e.g.

```
$items = Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\oop'
foreach ($item in $items) {
<#your processin with get-content here#>
echo $item.name
echo "$item-processed.txt"

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I misunderstodd in the first time. I hope I am right now:

You want so save one `done-File` per one input file.

The Problem with your code is that you are collection all the content of ***all*** Files in your `$lines-Variable`. And there is no Information about the underlying `File(-names)` any more. 
Instead you have to loop over all the files an handle them seperately.

**The solution suggested:**

```
$files = dir *.txt -Exclude *done.txt 
foreach ($f in $files) {
  Get-Content $f | % {$_.split(',')[0]} | 
    Out-File ($f.DirectoryName + '\' + $f.Basename + '-done.txt') -Encoding UTF8}
```

Regards Martin

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how I combine csv files into one big CSV.

```
$txtFilter  = "D:\Temp\*.csv"
$fileOutputSummary = "D:\Temp\Summary.csv"
$list = Get-ChildItem -Path $txtFilter | select FullName
$iItems = $list.Count
$i = 0
ForEach($file in $list){
    $i++
    Write-Host "Combining  ($i of $iItems) `r"
    Write-Progress -Activity "Combining CSV files" -PercentComplete ($i / $iItems*100) 
    Import-Csv -Path $file.FullName | Export-Csv -Path $fileOutputSummary -Append -NoTypeInformation 
    Sleep 1
} # end ForEach file
```

I hope my example helps.